# formatjs react-intl interpolation with custom components in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-intl, formatjs

We are using the `react-intl` library for translations inside the ReactNative project.  We don't use standard HTML tags like `<b>` or `<strong>` to format text.  Instead we have custom components like `<Text />` which are handled by the device.  But similar to a web app with custom components, it appears this library cannot handle this syntax [based on documentation](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#formatmessage):

```js
const messages = defineMessages({
    greeting: {
      defaultMessage: 'Hello, <bold>{name}</bold>!',
    },
  })

  return intl.formatMessage(messages.greeting, {
    name: 'Eric',
    bold: str => <b>{str}</b>,
  })
```

the reason being is that both `bold` & `b` tags are invalid in ReactNative.  So I tried swapping components with no luck.

Can interpolation be done with this library with custom components instead?